# How to solve import errors while trying to deploy Flask using WSGI on Apache2

Tags: python, apache, wsgi, flask

I am having an issue deploying a flask app on apache2 using wsgi. I have posted the error logs and config files below. I have tried moving things around, renaming them, etc, but all give me an internal server error. Not sure why I'm getting the import error. Any input / suggestions are appreciated, thanks!

Here is my apache error.log

```
[Sun Sep 12 20:47:59 2010] [error] [client] mod_wsgi (pid=9753): Target WSGI script '/sites/flaskfirst/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sun Sep 12 20:47:59 2010] [error] [client] mod_wsgi (pid=9753): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/sites/flaskfirst/wsgi.py'.
[Sun Sep 12 20:47:59 2010] [error] [client] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Sep 12 20:47:59 2010] [error] [client]   File "/sites/flaskfirst/wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
[Sun Sep 12 20:47:59 2010] [error] [client]     from app import app as application
[Sun Sep 12 20:47:59 2010] [error] [client] ImportError: No module named app
```

wsgi.py

```
# This is wsgi.py
from app import app as application
```

app.py

```
# This is app.py
from flask import Flask, render_template
import settings

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = settings.DEBUG

from views.homepage import *
from views.events import *
from views.submit import *
from views.feed import *

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Here is the basics of the directory tree, to give you an idea.

```
/flaskfirst/
    /static/
    /templates/
    /views/
    __init__.py
    app.py
    wsgi.py
```

Here is the apache virtualhost file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin sreustle@gmail.com
        ServerName crath.org
        DocumentRoot /sites/flaskfirst

        # WSGI Settings
        WSGIScriptAlias / /sites/flaskfirst/wsgi.py
        WSGIDaemonProcess flaskfirst user=sreustle group=general processes=1 threads=10
        WSGIProcessGroup flaskfirst

        # Static Directories
        Alias /static /sites/flaskfirst/static/
        <Location "/static">
                SetHandler None
        </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Thanks to `zarf` and `damjan` on irc.freenode.org at #pocoo, they were able to help me get this fixed. The problem was the PythonPath was not correct. We fixed this by using the following wsgi.py

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/sites/flaskfirst")

from app import app
application = app
```

Comment: Was having the same issue. I added it to `WSGIDaemonProcess appName python-path=/home/...` in my httpd config file.  Not sure if that is the correct place or not, but FWIW is an option. More about WSGIDaemonProcess: [link] (http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIDaemonProcess)

Comment: Thanks! You saved my day!!

Answer (score 4):

I used your solution to get it working but it kept duplicating the path in sys.path (you can write it out to see if it happens to you) so I made a little modification:

```
import sys
flaskfirst = "/sites/flaskfirst"
if not flaskfirst in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, flaskfirst)

from app import app
application = app
```

That way it's only included once