# Issues with Deploying Flask app on Ubuntu 14.04 VPS (Digital Ocean)

Tags: apache, ubuntu, flask, wsgi

I locally developed an awesome Flask app..now cannot seem to deploy for the life of me.

I am receiving a Internal Server Error with the following error logs:

```
[Sat May 03 22:24:11.355281 2014] [:error] [pid 17560:tid 139814473037568] [client 68.40.196.121:52221] mod_wsgi (pid=17560): Target WSGI script '/var/www/dhh/dhh.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sat May 03 22:24:11.355380 2014] [:error] [pid 17560:tid 139814473037568] [client 68.40.196.121:52221] mod_wsgi (pid=17560): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/dhh/dhh.wsgi'.
[Sat May 03 22:24:11.355467 2014] [:error] [pid 17560:tid 139814473037568] [client 68.40.196.121:52221] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sat May 03 22:24:11.355541 2014] [:error] [pid 17560:tid 139814473037568] [client 68.40.196.121:52221]   File "/var/www/dhh/dhh.wsgi", line 7, in 
[Sat May 03 22:24:11.355754 2014] [:error] [pid 17560:tid 139814473037568] [client 68.40.196.121:52221]     from dhh.app import app as application
[Sat May 03 22:24:11.355815 2014] [:error] [pid 17560:tid 139814473037568] [client 68.40.196.121:52221] ImportError: No module named dhh.app
```

#### Current File Structure Tree:

```
/dhh
|--/app
|------/static
|------/templates
|------__init__.py
|------views.py
|--/flask
|------/bin
|------/include
|------/lib
|------/local
|--/tmp
```

#### Relevant Files

1. `__init__.py`

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
from app import views

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

1. `views.py`

```
from app import app

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return "Hello, World! This better get working soon."
```

1. `/etc/apache2/sites-available/dhh.conf`

`ServerName davidhagan.me
        ServerAdmin david@davidhhagan.com
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/dhh/dhh.wsgi
        
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        
        Alias /static /var/www/dhh/dhh/app/static
        
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined`

1. `dhh.wsgi`

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/dhh/")

from dhh.app import app as application
application.secret_key = 'super secret key'
```

Although this is a very empty version of the app, it seems to be causing the errrors. I'm sure it is a simple mistake with how the apache server is setup, but cannot figure it out with other SO Q/A's. I would love to know not just how to fix this, but why it is happening!

## Update/Solution

I ended up needing to change the path as well as how I was calling the module.

```
sys.path.insert(0, "/var/www/dhh/")
```

becomes

```
sys.path.insert(0, "/var/www/dhh/dhh/")
```

and

```
from dhh.app import app as application
```

becomes

```
from app import app as application
```

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of [How to solve import errors while trying to deploy Flask using WSGI on Apache2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3696606/how-to-solve-import-errors-while-trying-to-deploy-flask-using-wsgi-on-apache2) - the key thing to remember is that Python imports what it can find in `sys.path` (and [a few other places](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html)) - if your app is not in Python's `path` it won't find it.

Comment: Thanks for the link, that question didn't pop up when I searched for some reason. Combined with the answer below, I got it to work. Updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
from dhh.app import app as application
```

use:

```
from app import app as application
```

Comment: Unfortunately, changing this left me with the same errors in the error log.

Comment: Presumably you might not have restarted Apache, because if the error still quoted exactly 'from dhh.app import app as application' then it didn't see the code change.