# Error on deploying Flask application using wsgi on apache2

Tags: python, apache, flask, wsgi

I am having a problem deploying a flask application on apache2 using mod_wsgi. Error log and config files follow. I always get internal server error. This is very similar to [How to solve import errors while trying to deploy Flask using WSGI on Apache2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3696606/how-to-solve-import-errors-while-trying-to-deploy-flask-using-wsgi-on-apache2) but for some reason the solution proposed there did not work here.

apache error log

```
[Thu Aug 27 12:06:30.366817 2015] [:error] [pid 9330:tid 140623686452992] [remote 2.239.9.178:64904] mod_wsgi (pid=9330): Target WSGI script '/var/www/bitcones/bitcones.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Thu Aug 27 12:06:30.366867 2015] [:error] [pid 9330:tid 140623686452992] [remote 2.239.9.178:64904] mod_wsgi (pid=9330): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/bitcones/bitcones.wsgi'.
[Thu Aug 27 12:06:30.366894 2015] [:error] [pid 9330:tid 140623686452992] [remote 2.239.9.178:64904] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Aug 27 12:06:30.366913 2015] [:error] [pid 9330:tid 140623686452992] [remote 2.239.9.178:64904]   File "/var/www/bitcones/bitcones.wsgi", line 4, in <module>
[Thu Aug 27 12:06:30.366969 2015] [:error] [pid 9330:tid 140623686452992] [remote 2.239.9.178:64904]     from bitcones import bitcones as application
[Thu Aug 27 12:06:30.366981 2015] [:error] [pid 9330:tid 140623686452992] [remote 2.239.9.178:64904]   File "/var/www/bitcones/bitcones/bitcones.py", line 6, in <module>
[Thu Aug 27 12:06:30.367045 2015] [:error] [pid 9330:tid 140623686452992] [remote 2.239.9.178:64904]     from analysis import cone as _cone, flow
[Thu Aug 27 12:06:30.367056 2015] [:error] [pid 9330:tid 140623686452992] [remote 2.239.9.178:64904]   File "/var/www/bitcones/bitcones/analysis/cone.py", line 5, in <module>
[Thu Aug 27 12:06:30.367121 2015] [:error] [pid 9330:tid 140623686452992] [remote 2.239.9.178:64904]     from analysis.statistics import purity_statistics
[Thu Aug 27 12:06:30.367139 2015] [:error] [pid 9330:tid 140623686452992] [remote 2.239.9.178:64904] ImportError: No module named analysis.statistics
```

bitcones.wsgi

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/bitcones")
from bitcones import bitcones as application
```

apache virtual host file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName <my-server-name>
    ServerAdmin <my-email>
    WSGIDaemonProcess bitcones user=<my-username> group=<my-username> threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/bitcones/bitcones.wsgi

<Directory /var/www/bitcones>
    WSGIProcessGroup bitcones
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

part of my app tree (everything is under /var/www/bitcones/)

```
├── bitcones
│   ├── analysis
│   │   ├── <some_files>
│   │   └── statistics
│   │   │   ├── <some_files>
│   ├── bitcones.py
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── <some static content>
│   └── templates
│       └── <my_templates>.html
└── bitcones.wsgi
```

This should be sufficient to figure out why I'm having this import error.
If any other file/configuration is needed please ask. I'm loosing my mind.

Thanks!

EDIT:
I just want to add that I was following this guide: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/mod_wsgi/

Comment: Is the cgi-script properly configured?

Comment: I'm not using cgi, I'm using mod_wsgi which is an implementation of wsgi, as far as I understood. Now, is my mod_wsgi script properly configured? I don't know...that's my question ;)

Comment: What Python version are you expecting to use and what is mod_wsgi using? You don't show any ``__init__.py`` files in your directories, which for most Python versions are required else your packages will not work. Beyond that, could be file system permissions, or SELinux restrictions.

Comment: Also, why isn't ``from analysis.statistics import purity_statistics`` instead ``from ..analysis.statistics import purity_statistics``? I would check how you are structuring your imports. It looks a bit like you have them written with an expectation that '/var/www/bitcones/bitcones' is also in ``sys.path``. So look at how relative imports work such that a module within a package can import something from above that point in the package.

Comment: `python --version` gives Python 2.7.6. How do I check which version of python my mod_wsgi is using? 

`__init__.py` files are in all the packages, I just did not report them in the question. Sorry! 

As for permission/restriction issues: what can I check? I have full access to the machine.

As for your second comment: everything is working fine locally with the development web server.

Thanks!

Comment: To check what version of Python mod_wsgi is using see sections of online documentation starting at https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation#Python_Shared_Library

Comment: Graham was right, changing `sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/bitcones")` to `sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/bitcones/bitcones")` fixed the problem. Also I had to change the import from `from bitcones import bitcones as application` to `from bitcones import app as application`.

I can't accept a comment as an answer right? What should I do now? Accept the Brian answer?

Answer (score 1):

You set the Python version that mod_wsgi uses when you install libapache2-mod-wsgi (python 2) or libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 (python 3). I would guess you're on Python 2 from what you describe, since using python 3 is a more deliberate choice than 2. I don't think that's your problem, though. I think it's an import problem, like Graham said.

I recommend using `from bitcones.analysis.statistics import purity_statistics` for your import statement.